# Ruby: Automatically create a post when user updates profile picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Users have the ability to create posts. They can also add (and update) their profile picture.

But I want to take this a step further. When a user updates their profile picture, I want the user to automatically create a post that says "Username updated their profile picture" and display the image below.

I am new to ruby and ruby on rails, I started learning about 1 month ago, so I could be wrong, but I was thinking I could achieve this with an if statement, such as:

```
if @user.avatar.save do
    #Post automated post
end
```

I commented because I have no idea what to type. But I know that someone with more knowledge could guide me (and the community) on how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you making social networking like post. And want to give notification to other users?

Comment: Yes. I am creating a social network. I want ruby to automatically create a post for a user when they update their profile picture. That post will be displayed on my posts/index page

Comment: What is name of model for activity to save and avatar to save ? and tell me relationship between them and user

Comment: I will add them. One minute, I will edit this post.

Comment: Are you using Paperclip for file attachment? If not how are the images being uploaded and attached to user objects?

Comment: Yes, I am using paperclip for images. And devise for users.

Comment: @Jarrel09 I do not use paper clip. There is a built in way to upload images if you need extra feature you need to use gem

Comment: I have been looking online trying to figure out this problem. If you guys need anymore code, let me know and I will post it. Thanks.

Comment: The controller we'll need to see is the User Controller, upload that as well. We'll want to modify the update action and stick the if statement there

Comment: Okay. I will upload it

Comment: I added my controllers

Comment: If you change the avatar, does the console command (using binding.pry or debugger) `current_user.avatar_changed?` return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `after_update` callback in your `User` model. This will call `create_avatar_post` method every time user avatar is successfully updated:

```
# This is in your user.rb file
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :post

    validates_uniqueness_of :username

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { large: "800x800>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "50x50>" }, default_url: "/assets/missing-user.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    after_update :create_avatar_post, if: :avatar_changed?

    def create_avatar_post
        Post.create(
            description: "#{username} update their profile picture",
            user_id: id
            # Whatever other attributes of Post
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: After updating image, I tried to visit user profile and got this error: `Routing error: undefined method `after_update' for UsersController:Class Did you mean? after_filter`

Comment: You need to put `after_update` in your model, not your controller. Make your controller as skinny as possible. And remove the comma after the `description` if it is your only attribute